# xsl:if at least one child node exists

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<node>
   <node1><node11/></node1>
   <node2/>
</node>
```

I want my XSLT to check

```
<xsl:if test="If at least 1 child node exists">
  Only node1 can pass the if condition
</xsl:if>
```

Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Firstly, be careful with your terminology here. Do you mean "node" or do you mean "element". A node can be an element, comment, text or processing-instruction.

Anyway, if you do mean element here, to check at least one child element exists, you can just do this (assuming you are positioned on the **node** element in this case.

```
<xsl:if test="*">
```

Your comment suggests only "node1" can pass the if condition, so to check the existence of a specific element, do this

```
<xsl:if test="node1">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a confusion among those terms. Will be more carefull next time

Answer (score 10):

In the context of the node you are testing, this should work to test whether a node has child *elements*:

```
<xsl:if test="*">
  Only node1 can pass the if condition
</xsl:if>
```

If you actually meant nodes (which would include text nodes), then this would work to include text nodes:

```
<xsl:if test="node()">
  Only node1 can pass the if condition
</xsl:if>
```

But `<node>` would also pass this test (`<node2>` wouldn't).  I assumed you were only speaking in the context of `<node>`'s child nodes, but perhaps not?

Answer (score 0):

Expressions that match a node are truthy, whilst expressions that don't match anything are falsy, so:

```
<xsl:if test="node()">
   ...
</xsl:if>
```

However, your question and the implied condition "Only node1 can pass the if condition" are at odds with the example.  Both `node` and `node1` have child nodes, so both would pass this if condition.

To limit it strictly to `node1`, you have to either ensure that the template context is appropriate, or check that the node in question is not the documentElement.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question is unclear but I think you just want to process child nodes that have themselves got children (ie grandchildren of the current node)

```
<xsl:template match="node">
 do stuff for node
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*[*]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

will just apply templates to `node1` as it has a child node, it will not apply templates to `node2`.